# Minimum number of boxes we need to pack the items

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, discrete-optimization

We have $N$ items of the same size and we want to them in boxes. We have boxes of different sizes $\{M_1,\ldots , M_k\}$, how many we want from each size. Each box has be fully filled.

Design an algorithm that calculates the minimum number of boxes we need to pack the items.

We consider $M_1=1$ to have always fully boxes independent of $N$.

$$$$

It looks like Knapsack problem. So do we have to apply the algorithm of Knapsack problem for each box?

So we could sort the boxes in increasing order as for the size.

Then we starting packing items in that box, if it gets full we go to the next box.

We do that till no items are left.

Is the idea correct?

Comment: Your explanation is rather confusing. Do we have an unlimited number of boxes of each size? And I think you mean that $M_1$ is always equal to $1$, to guarantee that a solution exists. Also, please clarify what you mean by "that box".

Comment: Yes we have an unlimited number of boxes of each size. By "that box" you mean at my idea? I thought we start with the smallest sized box and fill some items,if it is full we go to the next size and so on... @TonyK

Comment: Do we have to modify Knapsack problem? Or is there an other approach?@TonyK

Comment: But if we have an unlimited supply of boxes of size $1$, you will never fill them all, so you will use $N$ boxes of size $1$! Obviously it is better to start with the largest size.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We indeed can solve it as Knapsack problem - for each $n \leq N$ calculate $a_n$ - minimum number of boxes we need for $n$ items by recurrent
$$a_n = \begin{cases}
\infty, & n < 0 \\
0, & n = 0 \\
1 + \min_i a_{n - M_i}, & n > 0
\end{cases}$$

Greedy algorithm doesn't work, as usual: let $N = 10$, $M_2 = 6$, $M_3 = 5$. Then greedy algorithm uses one box of size $6$ and $4$ boxes of size $1$ for a total of $5$ boxes, while optimal solution is to use two boxes of size $5$.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)